# error TS1316 Global module exports may only appear at top level

Tags: typescript, npm, q, tsc

Having trouble building an old typescript project. Unable to build an old project that I am coming back to. There is an issue with ***q*** when trying to build. I assume it is my tsc version, but every version I have tried results in errors.

There were some suggestions online to change the typescript version to past 2.2 because it handles typings differently, but nothing has resulted in any progress.

I have provided error information, and versions. Also my tsconfig.json. Please let me know if you need more information.

**Errors** *($tsc -v 2.1.5)*

```
$ tsc -p ./
typings/modules/q/index.d.ts(10,1): error TS1316: Global module exports may only appear at top level.
```

**Versions**

```
nvm: 1.1.5
npm: 4.1.2
tsc: 2.1.5
node: 7.5.0

$ npm list --depth=0
+-- @types/q@1.5.1
`-- typescript@2.1.5
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "outDir": "static/js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "files": [
        "typings/index.d.ts",
        "../common/types.d.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

**EDIT**

The errors listed under tsc v2.3.0 were actually still 2.1.5. I didn't install typepscript globally, so it was still using 2.1.5 instead of 2.3.0 when I ran the tsc command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When errors show up in declaration files, it's generally an indication that the declaration file uses syntax which is not available in your version of TypeScript.

In this case, let's take a look at the lines reported as errors.

```ts
64: then<U = T, V = never>(onFulfill?: ...
200: thenReject<U = T>(reason?: any): Promise<U>;
```

The errors reported here point to the equal signs in the type arguments section. This indicates that default type arguments aren't supported. This doesn't really make sense since support for [default type arguments](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/04/27/announcing-typescript-2-3/#default-type-arguments) was added in TS2.3. My best guess is that you didn't actually have 2.3 installed for those errors, and the versions were switched...

With that in mind, the other errors are likely due to incompatibility between the old (<2.1, if I recall correctly) `typings` files and the new `@types` files. With the types installed in `node_modules/@types/q`, you don't need to include a custom `typings` folder, so you should be able to delete `typings/modules/q` (in fact, the whole `typings` folder) to resolve the other error.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, a project to clone would make it much easier to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: You are right, the 2.3.0 errors were the same as 2.1.5 because I didn't install typescript as global when i set it to 2.3.0. I set tsc to 2.3.0, removed typings, and installed q through @types instead. Thanks for your help!